# I am trying to get data from Input from button click using jquery but on alert it's shows nothing

Tags: jquery, input

I am expecting to show whatever the value I am giving should show on alert but it's showing nothing on alert.

```js
$("#save-button").click(() => {
  var total_tax = $("#tax-input1").val();
  alert(total_tax);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tax-input1" class="form-control input-style" type="text" id="email">
<button id="save-button" class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Save</button>
```

Comment: Your code works in isolation - as you can see in the snippet I edited in to your question. I'm guessing your issue is because in your full local version you're using a `submit` button inside a `form` element which is causing a page redirection, so the page is unloaded before the `alert()` can be displayed. If so, change your logic to either be fired from a different event, or to prevent the form submission until after the alert